# redirecting users if server is overcrowded or busy using php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

is it possible to use php to redirect users to page `i.e. busy.php` when the server is busy or overcrowded, or something similiar? thanks :))

Comment: wouldnt it be better to add a second server and use a loadbalancer to divide load between them instead of telling the user he cannot use your site right now?

Comment: Whilst that may be a useful suggestion, you're effectively telling him to "get another server", which I assume is not what he wants.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if the server is busy and slowly executing PHP as a result, the PHP to detect this and redirect the user will also execute slowly.

Comment: @Kevin yes, it's not what was asked (which is why it is a comment only), but it's not unreasonable to think about it as an alternative because it indicates the need for scaling out. @James the load balancer is unlikely to be implemented in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHP Internal Functions like memory-get-usage http://php.net/manual/de/function.memory-get-usage.php or access a Shell Script that gives you some kind of Information about the current load of the Server. And then depending on that Information set a Redirect via Headers.

However, Remember that if your server breaks down, most likely the PHP Script wouldn't be executed and no redirect would happen. So, depending on your Infrastructure you can handle this over a secondary Server (a Load-Balancer perhaps).

If you can narrow down the most likely cause of a breakdown, try to fetch it there, for example if your MySQL Connection fails, fetch that, and direct the User to your "busy page".

Comment: Doesn't that function just tell you the memory usage of the current PHP process, not a system wide total?

Answer (score 4):

I second [using a dedicated load balancer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) instead of doing this with PHP. But if this is not an option for some reason, you can try with [`sys_getloadavg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php):

> Returns three samples representing the average system load (the number of processes in the system run queue) over the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes, respectively.

**Example from Manual:**

```
<?php
$load = sys_getloadavg();
if ($load[0] > 80) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
    die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
}
?>
```

The [implementation in php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L6073) uses [getloadavg](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getloadavg) under the hood. So the values returned are the same you'd get from running `cat /proc/loadavg` or `uptime`.

A simple explanation of [Linux load averages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) can be found at http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages:

> On multi-processor system, the load is relative to the number of processor cores available. The "100% utilization" mark is 1.00 on a single-core system, 2.00, on a dual-core, 4.00 on a quad-core, etc.

Also see https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-on-unix-linux

Comment: I would like to know, if this really works. I'm getting 0.80 to 1.5 values, is 80 a relevant value? What is the max value from this? I can't find a good definition for this on the web

Comment: thanks, that explains my numbers on my 8 core machine

Answer (score 1):

The best aproach is to use a load balancer but just in case you can redirect to a busy page (that can't use DB connection at all) with this piece of code on your setup class:

```
class [...] {
    [...]
    public function connect(){
        $this->conn = @mysql_connect ([...]) 
            or $this->dbError("Failed MySQL connection");
        [...]
    }

    private function dbError($msg){
        include("busy.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, would prefer try/fetch and a redirect to an existing static page (temporary redirect to prevent an SEO mess)

Comment: instead of 30X redirect, my busy page uses 'HTTP 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable' and 'Retry-After: 3600' that is, in my opinion, better because prevent the busy page to be indexed